# How to run libpysal.weights.Distanceband without kernel crashing?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, spatial, weighting

I have a dataset that has longitudes and latitudes, and the number of elections a given individual has voted in the elections. My goal is to run a G_Local as I would like to identify
the degree of clustering that happens for the number of elections people participated in.

To do this, I started by creating a geometry column with the following code snippet, `df_coords = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(df['LONGITUDE'], df['LATITUDE'])]`. This work fine.

And so I moved onto the next step which is to set the spatial weights, `libpysal.weights.DistanceBand`. Because this required me to only provide the coordinates, without the geom_type, I ran the following code snippet:

```
newpt = []

lat = df['LATITUDE']
long = df['LONGITUDE']

for item1, item2 in zip(long, lat):
    a = (item1, item2)
    newpt.append(a)
```

This too worked fine. The issue begins when I try to execute the weights, `w = libpysal.weights.DistanceBand(newpt, threshold = 10)`

Whenever I try to execute the weights, my kernel crashes. Without being able to execute the weights, I can't continue onto running G_local.

Please help. Thank you in advance!

I tried lowering the threshold thinking that it may lower the memory requirements but kernel still crashes.